# How to keep span and input in a div in the same line/row ?

Tags: html, css

I have a piece of code which looks like :

```
<div id="my_reg_id" class="form-group col-xs-12 col-lg-4 col-sm-8 col-md-8" style="margin-bottom: -20px;">

<label id="lbl_my_reg_id" class="error_lbl control-label" for="txtRegId"></label>

<input id="txtRegId" class="form-control hint_sel" type="text" name="txtRegId" value="" maxlength="20" placeholder="*My Reg id ">

<span id="errmsg_my_reg_id" class="help-block error hidden-all" style="line-height:17px"></span>

<span id="instr_my_reg_id" class="help-block " style="">
<a class="font-size-12 sm-padding-l-3p sm-line-height-3 padding-a-5 js-p6-forgotID" href="#">Forgot Reg ID?</a></span>

</div>
```

Now I want the span id `instr_my_reg_id`  and the input id `txtRegId` in the same line , but in my case , the input element is coming in one line and the span element is coming in the next line .

What can i do to rectify this ?

PS: I have tried using `inline-block` as a style in the wrapper div but that did not work.

Comment: Really, I just paste the whole code. and `span` and `input` tag in same line. http://jsbin.com/yosecaqi/1/edit

Answer (score 0):

use css

```
float:left;
```

in all elements. whom you want to align in a linear way

```
<input style='float:left'/>
<span style='float:left'>....</span>
```

Comment: display:inline-block is better than float:left

Comment: it will auto sized and measure width of container .